# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animObject' of undefined highcharts-3d.src.js:306

Tags: javascript, laravel, highcharts

I was using highcharts for long time.
Today suddenly i'm getting this error for highchart 3D.

My scripts:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/highchart/highcharts.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/highchart/exporting.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/highchart/export-data.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/highchart/accessibility.js') }}"></script>
```

Error

```
   highcharts-3d.src.js:306 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animObject' of undefined
   at highcharts-3d.src.js:306
   at G (highcharts-3d.src.js:26)
   at highcharts-3d.src.js:294
   at highcharts-3d.src.js:20
   at highcharts-3d.src.js:9
```

Comment: This looks like an issue of the 3rd party script you are requesting (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js). Either it didn't load properly, or they were breaking changes.

Comment: I've tried both CDN and downloaded to my local. Arranged the scripts as mentioned in their docs.
NB: everything was ok. Nothing changed from the last time it was working properly.

Comment: Hi @Khairat Hossin, There are probably some mismatch between `highcharts` and `highcharts-3d`. You always need to use the same Highcharts and modules version. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2r6xnkyv/